# bananas (are vs is) a whole different story?

Tags: grammar, differences, prepositions

Imagine I'm talking to someone about a certain thing and then that person compares bananas to it, I don't think the comparison is valid, so I say "no, bananas are a whole different story", is it correct? Or do I say "is a whole different story"?

Comment: The word "bananas" is plural so you use "are".  Unless like me you're talking about the word rather than the fruit: the word "bananas" is a whole different story.

Comment: The usage "bananas" here refers to an irrelevant comparison. So it is better to be considered as singular and say "No, bananas is a whole different story".

Comment: There are arguments both ways (as others' opinions have already shown). And arguments against both ways. The use of 'That's' to cover notionally singular as well as formally singular antecedents (perhaps 'The bananas situation is ...') is almost universally accepted, so I'd choose that.